# get checked option value in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have input group include `2` options `checkbox` and `input` field.

> I want to `get value of input field` **only if checkbox is checked**
>   otherwise ignore that input field.

## Codes

```
@foreach($list as $columns)
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
  </span>
  <input type="text" name="{{$columns}}" value="{{$columns}}" class="form-control">
</div><!-- /input-group -->
@endforeach
```

currently I get all my inputs in my controller regardless they are checked or not:

```
$column = $request->except('_token');
```

How do I pass this to my controller function?

## UPDATE

`as requested` : my code `$list` dd is:

```
array:27 [▼
  0 => "id"
  1 => "title"
  2 => "slug"
  3 => "imageOne"
  4 => "imageTwo"
  5 => "short_description"
  6 => "description"
  7 => "price"
  8 => "meta_description"
  9 => "meta_tags"
  10 => "arrivalDays"
  11 => "height"
  12 => "weight"
  13 => "lenght"
  14 => "width"
  15 => "sku"
  16 => "stock"
  17 => "label"
  18 => "label_from"
  19 => "label_to"
  20 => "label_color"
  21 => "status_id"
  22 => "brand_id"
  23 => "category_id"
  24 => "subcategory_id"
  25 => "created_at"
  26 => "updated_at"
]
```

## UPDATE 2

To be clear how it works exactly i included screenshot

[SEE IT](https://image.ibb.co/dkJDLS/ddddd.jpg)

Comment: Maybe you want to assign a `name` attribute to your checkbox

Comment: @linktoahref name to be what `{{columns}}` ? and how to validate it in controller?

Comment: Would `$columns` be unique?

Comment: @linktoahref yes is name of my table columns.

Comment: @mafortis mind if I try some jQuery?

Comment: @EazySam whatever it works dude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## SOLVED

First of all I have to thank everyone who tried to help me solve this issue specially **`Wahyu Fadzar`**. Here is how I solved my issue:

I changed my blade code to:

```
@php $no = 0; @endphp //Wahyu Fadzar idea
@foreach($list as $columns)
@php $no+=1; @endphp //Wahyu Fadzar idea
<div class="input-group">
<span class="input-group-addon">
<input type="checkbox"  name="cb[{{$no}}]" checked="checked"> //Wahyu Fadzar idea
</span>
<input type="text" name="customname[{{$no}}]" value="{{$columns}}" //Wahyu Fadzar ideaclass="form-control">
<input type="hidden" name="defaultname[{{$no}}]" value="{{$columns}}"> // Added
</div><!-- /input-group -->
@endforeach
```

`Controller`

```
public function export(Request $request) {
// defaultname that i added in my blade used here (explaination below)
      $input = $request->except('_token');
      foreach ($input['cb'] as $key => $value) {
        if ($value== 'on') {
          $getRealInput[$key] = $input['defaultname'][$key];
        }
      }

      $products = Product::select($getRealInput)->get(); //getting table selected columns
      Excel::create('products', function($excel) use($products, $request) {
        $excel->sheet('sheet 1', function($sheet) use($products, $request){
//Wahyu Fadzar code used here to get selected columns data
          $input = $request->except('_token');
          foreach ($input['cb'] as $key => $value) {
            if ($value== 'on') {
              $getCustomInput[$key] = $input['customname'][$key];
            }
          }

          $sheet->fromArray($products, null, 'A1', false, false);
          $sheet->row(1, $getCustomInput);
        });
      })->export('csv');
      return redirect()->back();
    }
```

## Explanations

1. I had issue before when I used **Wahyu** code it would remove my inputs from `CSV` file as i unchecked them, but their data still exist in my file
   so I added

> < input type = " hidden " name = " defaultname[{{$no}}] " value = " {{$columns}} " >

and by this i will get my default column names even if i edit it for export. otherwise it would return error, eg. I changed my `title` column to `name` it says `there is no column name!` so by this my `title` column will stay `title` for select query.

I used it in:

> $products = Product::select($getRealInput)->get();

2. I used Wahyu code in my export part in order to get custom input names for my `CSV` file and not the default ones.

> < input type = " text " name = " customname[{{$no}}] " value = "
>   {{$columns}} " class = " form-control " >

goes to:

```
if ($value== 'on') {
  $getCustomInput[$key] = $input['customname'][$key];
}
```

inside my export query.

Hope it help others as well.

THANK YOU ALL.

Answer (score 1):

1) change the name of checkbox to cb[] and input to input[]

```
@php
 $no = 0;
@endphp
@foreach($list as $columns)
@php
  $no+=1;
@endphp
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <input type="checkbox" name="cb[{{$no}}]" checked="checked">
    </span>
    <input type="text" name="input[{{$no}}]" value="{{$columns}}" class="form-control">
  </div><!-- /input-group -->
@endforeach
```

2)filter your $request and include just the checked checkbox

```
$input = $request->except('_token');
foreach ($input['cb'] as $key => $value) {
  if ($value== 'on') {
    $getRealInput[$key] = $input['input'][$key];
  }
}
return $getRealInput;
```

Comment: for example i `unchecked` title but i have it as `1 "title"` in my results

Comment: `$no`? where this coming from? `Undefined variable: no`

Comment: i define it before foreach

Comment: mine was success...
have u include my code before foreach?

Comment: oh no! sorry i try again

Comment: ok i tried it, `it is working` but not 100%, for all columns if i uncheck they will not include my export file except `id` if i uncheck it the label of id will remove from my file but table id's still will be in there `screenshot`  https://ibb.co/mZQ4S7

Comment: bro i changed your code (advanced it) and now it's working as i expected, I vote up your answer but i'm going to share full answer. Appreciate all your helps without your helps i coudn't make it happen.  THANK YOU.

Answer (score 0):

You could name the checkbox as an array

```
@foreach($list as $columns)
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <input type="checkbox" name="cb[]" value="{{ $columns }}">
  </span>
  <input type="text" name="{{$columns}}" value="{{$columns}}" class="form-control">
</div><!-- /input-group -->
@endforeach
```

and in your controller you could get the checked items as

```
foreach ($request->cb as $checked) {
    $request->{$checked} // The textbox corresponding to the selected checkbox
}
```

Comment: just return `0 => "on"` 26 times

Comment: @mafortis try with the `checked` attribute being removed

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

1) first of all mention checkbox name like this :

```
@foreach($list as $columns)
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
  </span>
  <input type="text" name="{{$columns}}" value="{{$columns}}" class="form-control">
</div><!-- /input-group -->
@endforeach
```

2) In Controller try this:

```
$inputs  = asset($request->checkbox) && $request->checkbox !='' ? $request->except('_token') : []; //if you want to remove input fields use unset inputs instead of []
dd($inputs)
```

Comment: it gives me all my inputs  + new field `"checkbox" => "on"`

Comment: have you tried without checkbox checked? it will give you blank it sure.

Comment: can you please paste here output of $columns variable.?

Comment: yes that was result of mix selected and unselected options, `updated`

Comment: what do you mean by mix selected?

Comment: i have 26 inputs 26 checkbox, i tried your code while i made some checked and some not. (mix)

Comment: Paste here output of your variable $list. I will help you out to find this solution.

Comment: Okay. Just make hidden field for every row inside loop and assign id something similar with hidden field. If checkbox name is name="checkbox_1" hidden field id should be id="hidden_1" and name="hidden[]" . Using jquery assign value to corresponding hidden field if checkbox is checked else remove hidden field value.  and when you post to server inputs fields value and hidden fields value will be equal. And make 1 variable on server side like $finalData = array() before loop start and loop through the all inputs and compare if hidden field value is empty don't assign value to $finalData array.

Comment: i think we don't need all that trouble because `$columns` is unique itself, as is my table column names like `id` `title` `slug` etc. all i need is to match checkbox name with input name eg. `checkbox name="{{$columns}}" //which is title` and `input name="{{$columns}} //which is title as well` is loop.

Comment: @mafortis if you did not checked checkbox it will not post data to server that the problem you will face.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

**Updated Answer:**

```
@foreach($list as $columns)
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <input type="checkbox" name="columns[]" value="{{ $columns }}">
      </span>
      <input type="text" name="{{$columns}}" value="{{$columns}}" class="form-control">
    </div><!-- /input-group -->
@endforeach
```

**In controller :**

```
$columns = $request->columns;

print_r($columns);
```

Comment: no bro you get it wrong the main point is to have input field separate with checkbox because checkbox works as it to be included export result or not, but input field itself is for customize the value($columns)

Comment: @mafortis: You mean input field have separate checkbox?

Comment: yes, as you see in my codes. if checkbox is checked my input data will be included my export file otherwise no. (try to copy my codes in some html file you'll see)

Comment: @mafortis:You can get checked checkbox input value from my Updated answer

Answer (score 0):

First of all, identify each checkboxes with unique names(use `columns[]`). 
Here I guess you don't expect manual entry(modification) as you populate the value of `$columns` in your **`text input field`**. If so, yoou could use a `label` instead:

```
@foreach($list as $key => $columns)
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <input name="columns[]" type="checkbox" value={{$key}} checked="checked">
  </span>
  <label class="form-control">{{$columns}}</label>
</div>
@endforeach
```

**UPDATE:**

> VIEW

```
@foreach($list as $key => $columns) 
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <input name="col_keys[]" type="checkbox" value={{$key}} checked="checked">
    </span>
    <input type="text" name="col_texts[]" value="{{$columns}}" class="form-control">
@endforeach
```

> CONTROLLER

Now `$request->col_keys` will have an **array of keys** that are valid for  `$request->col_texts`. So do a sorting:

```
$valid_keys = $request->col_keys;
$all_texts  = $reqest->col_texts;

foreach($all_texts as $key => $item) {
    if (($key = array_search($key, $valid_keys)) === false) {
        unset($all_texts($key));
    }
}
```

Comment: `in case if you need the text field to identify separately.` the main point is to have input field separate with checkbox because checkbox works as saying `input field` to `be included` export result `or not`, but input field itself `is for customize the value($columns)`

Comment: @mafortis Hope the latest update in my answer can help to solve your problem.

Comment: ` Can't use function return value in write context` in `unset($all_texts($key));`

Comment: Try: `value={{$key}} ` in the view form. Answer updated!